# GoogleMobileVision GoogleSignIn duplicate symbol using Cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods, google-signin, duplicate-symbol, google-ios-vision

I am using CocoaPods to add two frameworks.

```
target 'TestGoogleLib' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestGoogleLib
    pod 'GoogleMobileVision'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'


end
```

But when I run - I get duplicate error. It seems both framework are using same file.

My Pod version is **1.5.3**

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._localAuthenticationInfo in:


ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I install both using CocoaPods without conflicts --- I removed all conflicts logs - if needed, I can add them.

Comment: You may need to `pod repo update`. What's in your Podfile.lock?  Are you getting the latest versions?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I'm getting the same issue.  My pods are up to date:  GoogleMobileVision (1.3.2) and GoogleSignIn (4.2.0).  I tried 'pod repo update' as well.  I downgraded GoogleSignIn to 4.1.2 and it compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue with the `GoogleMobileVision` and `GoogleSignIn` pods including the same symbols in their builds. See this [discussion](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8015).

Until the build issue is resolved in one or both of those pods, a workaround is to back up the version of `GoogleSignIn`:

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '4.1.2'
```