# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 for GoogleSignIn and GoogleMobileVision

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-signin

not sure if there is anything I can do to fix this?

> duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._localAuthenticationInfo in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._keychainInfo in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._hasLocalAuthentication
>   in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._hasKeychain in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._cachedState in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._keychainExpireTime in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MDMPasscodeCache in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MDMPasscodeCache in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._hasEnteredBackground
>   in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeState._status in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeState_d2697588db599ad1e82d46f342216cee.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeState_adbe96d99863168799049cc0f0164c6d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeState._info in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeState_d2697588db599ad1e82d46f342216cee.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeState_adbe96d99863168799049cc0f0164c6d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MDMPasscodeState in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeState_d2697588db599ad1e82d46f342216cee.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeState_adbe96d99863168799049cc0f0164c6d.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MDMPasscodeState in:
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeState_d2697588db599ad1e82d46f342216cee.o)
>       /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECT/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeState_adbe96d99863168799049cc0f0164c6d.o)
>   ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: nm, found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869996/googlemobilevision-googlesignin-duplicate-symbol-using-cocoapods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GoogleMobileVision GoogleSignIn duplicate symbol using Cocoapods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869996/googlemobilevision-googlesignin-duplicate-symbol-using-cocoapods)

Comment: @kerberos yes it is, the solution on that thread works for me

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to build ios by modifying the file

> google_sign_in.podspec

tucked in the following directory

> /Users/⁨peter/dev⁩ ▸ ⁨flutter⁩ ▸ ⁨.pub-cache⁩ ▸ ⁨hosted⁩ ▸
>   ⁨pub.dartlang.org⁩ ▸ ⁨google_sign_in-3.0.5⁩ ▸ ⁨ios⁩

```
s.dependency 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

These commands might work.

[More detail.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44305#issuecomment-557074487)

> This issue is still reoccurring from time to time.
>   What I usually do is run these codes below and then use flutter clean to clean up.
>   It works as a temporary fix for me as I have no idea how to fix it permanently.

```
  cd ios/
  pod cache clean --all
  pod deintegrate --verbose
  pod setup --verbose
  pod install --verbose
```